# Retrieve dijit elements by class

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I would like to retrieve a dijit element by class. Based on these [docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/registry.html#usage), I've attempted the code below. I have a couple of dijit/form/ToggleButtons on a dijit/Toolbar for some map functions and I am trying to work out the toggle. Problem is, I am getting: 'Uncaught TypeError: dijit.registry.byClass is not a function'

```
require([
  "esri/geometry/Extent",
  "esri/toolbars/navigation",
  "dojo/on",
  "dijit/registry",
  "dijit/Toolbar",
  "dijit/form/Button",
  "dijit/form/ToggleButton"
  //"dojo/domReady!"
],
function (Extent, Navigation, on, registry, Toolbar, Button, ToggleButton) {


  var navToolbar;

  navToolbar = new Navigation(window.myMap);


  var zoomInButton = new ToggleButton({
    label: "Zoom Avant",
    showLabel: false,
    iconClass: "zoominIcon",
    checked: false,
    onClick: function () {
      //alert("test button clicked")
      navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_IN);
      toggleButtonIcon(this);
    }
  }, "zoomin");
  zoomInButton.startup();

  var zoomOutButton = new ToggleButton({
    label: "Zoom Arrière",
    showLabel: false,
    iconClass: "zoomoutIcon",
    onClick: function () {
      //alert("test button clicked")
      navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);
      toggleButtonIcon(this);
    }
  }, "zoomout");
  zoomOutButton.startup();


  //this toggles the button highlight in the toolbar to show which tool is currently active
  //note - doesn't do the FullExtent since it's a button not a togglebutton
  function toggleButtonIcon(tool) {
    //only the tools in the toolbar are dijit togglebuttons so can iterate thru them
    dijit.registry.byClass("dijit.form.ToggleButton").forEach(function(togbtn) {
      if (togbtn == tool) {
        togbtn.attr("checked", true);
      }
      else {
        togbtn.attr("checked", false);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="toolContainer">
  <div class="navBarClass" id="navToolbar" data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar" data-dojo-props="region:'top'" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
    <button type="button" id="zoomin"></button>
    <button type="button" id="zoomout"></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**: I'm noticing on [this docs page](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html) some additional info that may be related. I'm now, however, confused as to what my options are (new to dojo). I'm looking to use dojo/query. I need to be able to distinguish just a couple buttons from the others based on class.

> Note that for backwards compatibility, the dijit.registry global
>   variable (as opposed to the dijit/registry module) includes array
>   iterator methods (forEach, filter, byClass, map, every, and some).
>   However, AMD code should not expect these functions to be available in
>   the Object returned from require([“dijit/registry”]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand, how [this](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/registry.html#usage) is working. Here two methods are chained. The complete call is:

```
dijit.registry.forEach(function(w){
     w.containerNode.appendChild(dojo.create("div"));
}).byClass("dijit.Dialog").forEach(function(w){ /* only dijit.Dialog instances */ });
```

Thr first method, `dijit.registry.forEach()` returns an instance of `dijit/WidgetSet` ([Doc](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/WidgetSet.html)). The `dijit/WidgetSet` instance has a method `byClass`. What this method does is, that it reduces the initial `WidgetSet` to a new `WidgetSet` instance that will contain only those widgets which have `declaredClass` as `dijit.Dialog` in this case.

To retrieve dijit elements by class, you can use a combination of `dojo/query` and `registry/getEnclosingWidget`. First query all the DOM nodes of the widget using the class.

```
var domNodes= query('.myClass', this.domNode);
```

And then, iterate over this list to find the widget corresponding to each domNode.

```
domNodes.forEach(function(domNode){
    var widget= registry.getEnclosingWidget(domNode);
    //do your processing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`dijit.registry.byClass` does not exist in their API as described in the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: dijit.registry.byClass is not a function`.

You can also from dijit documentation:

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/registry

To find a widget you could use instead one of the following functions of `dijit.registry`:

- `byId(id)` Find a widget by it's id (I would recommend you to use this one).
- `byNode(node)` Returns the widget corresponding to the given DOMNode
- `findWidgets(root,skipNode)` Search subtree under root returning widgets found.